# Function implementing interface

Tags: go

I want to know what is happening here.

There is the interface for a http handler:

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(*Conn, *Request)
}
```

This implementation I think I understand.

```
type Counter int

func (ctr *Counter) ServeHTTP(c *http.Conn, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(c, "counter = %d\n", ctr);
    ctr++;
}
```

From my understanding it is that the type "Counter" implements the interface since it has a method that has the required signature. So far so good. Then this example is given:

```
func notFound(c *Conn, req *Request) {
    c.SetHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;", "charset=utf-8");
    c.WriteHeader(StatusNotFound);
    c.WriteString("404 page not found\n");
}

// Now we define a type to implement ServeHTTP:
type HandlerFunc func(*Conn, *Request)
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(c *Conn, req *Request) {
    f(c, req) // the receiver's a func; call it
}
// Convert function to attach method, implement the interface:
var Handle404 = HandlerFunc(notFound);
```

Can somebody elaborate on why or how these various functions fit together?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This:

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(*Conn, *Request)
}
```

says that any type which satisfies the `Handler` interface must have a `ServeHTTP` method. The above would be inside the package `http`.

```
type Counter int

func (ctr *Counter) ServeHTTP(c *http.Conn, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(c, "counter = %d\n", ctr);
    ctr++;
}
```

This puts a method on the Counter type which corresponds to ServeHTTP. This is an example which is separate from the following.

> From my understanding it is that the
>   type "Counter" implements the
>   interface since it has a method that
>   has the required signature.

That's right.

The following function by itself won't work as a `Handler`:

```
func notFound(c *Conn, req *Request) {
    c.SetHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;", "charset=utf-8");
    c.WriteHeader(StatusNotFound);
    c.WriteString("404 page not found\n");
}
```

The rest of this stuff is just fitting the above so that it can be a `Handler`.

In the following, a `HandlerFunc` is a function which takes two arguments, *pointer to `Conn`* and *pointer to `Request`*, and returns nothing. In other words, any function which takes these arguments and returns nothing can be a `HandlerFunc`.

```
// Now we define a type to implement ServeHTTP:
type HandlerFunc func(*Conn, *Request)
```

Here `ServeHTTP` is a method added to the type `HandlerFunc`:

```
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(c *Conn, req *Request) {
    f(c, req) // the receiver's a func; call it
}
```

All it does is to call the function itself (`f`) with the arguments given.

```
// Convert function to attach method, implement the interface:
var Handle404 = HandlerFunc(notFound);
```

In the above line, `notFound` has been finagled into being acceptable for the interface for `Handler` by artificially creating a type instance out of the function itself and making the function into the `ServeHTTP` method for the instance. Now `Handle404` can be used with the `Handler` interface. It's basically a kind of trick.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, the thing that tripped me up was the conversion of notFound to HandlerFunc. After rereading the conversions section of effective go it is more clear how that can also apply to functions.

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#conversions

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I was having a hard time understanding the reason behind all this gymnastics, even got donwvotes on my own SO question on it. Your answer explains it the way it should be done. And word 'trick' explains the 'reason' behind it much better:).

Answer (score -2):

What exactly don't you understand about the second half?  It's the same pattern as above.  Instead of defining the Counter type as an int, they define a function called notFound.  They then create a type of function called HandlerFunc that takes two parameters, a connection and a request.  they then create a new method called ServeHTTP, that gets bound to the HandlerFunc type.  Handle404 is simply an instance of this class that uses the notFound function.

Comment: Yeah, it's typical higher order functional programming. It can be confusing the first time you see it and work your way through the types.