# Why would you implement an interface on a function in Go?

Tags: function, go, types, interface, functional-programming

I was reading that, in Go, functions can implement interfaces ([like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774225/function-implementing-interface) or [this example](https://karthikkaranth.me/blog/functions-implementing-interfaces-in-go/)).

But what value is there in having a function implement an interface?

For example, why take the time to define an interface, a new type for the function, and a method, like this:

```golang
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(*Conn, *Request)
}

type HandlerFunc func(*Conn, *Request)

func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(c *Conn, req *Request) {
    f(c, req)
}
```

when instead you could just create a single function like this:

```golang
func ServeHTTP(f func(*Conn, *Request), c *Conn, req *Request) {
    f(c, req)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Single function interface vs a function type are just a preference, I don't see any _"objective" technical reasons_ to prefer one over the other.

Comment: For me, a handler could have own states. Such a design covers that case. Just think about your second cited link, the "counter" handler.

Comment: The point of using an interface is that you can re-use that same interface with any type that satisfies it's requirements. I don't see how you can think that your two examples are in any way equivalent.

Comment: @super with function type there is no problem to reuse it either: if a function matches the required type - it can be passed. There is no _technical_ advantage of using one solution or the other, they are really similar.

Comment: @p1gd0g there really is no problem in keeping state with function types: https://play.golang.org/p/7No83RkEgRE

Comment: @zerkms Technically true, but not very useful way of looking at it. What about expressing intent, readability, decoupling and easier to extend at a later time to name a few reasons interfaces and a single function type are not in any way equivalent.

Comment: @super from my 20y experience in software development and design (using all possible languages and paradigms) - in this case I would prefer a function type, to me it's more flexible and clear :shrug: (but in case of `io.Reader` I agree the interface is better)

Comment: @zerkms It works but has a misunderstanding "handler" defination. But I agree it opinion-based.

Comment: They are called "Methods" specifically/idiomatically in Go. 

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A single function (in your example, `func ServeHTTP`, doesn't satisfy any interfaces.

The reason to attach a method to a function type is therefore *to satisfy an interface*.

What value is there in this?  The same value in having any other type implement an interface. Let's look at the `http.Handler` interface, since you brought that up.

```golang
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

You can implement this interface with, for example, a struct:

```golang
type myHanlder struct {
   /* some fields */
}

func (s *myHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /* do things */
}
```

You could also satisfy it with some simpler type. Say, a string:

```golang
type myStringHandler string

func (h myStringHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "The string is: %s", h)
}
```

But if you want to just implement the function directly, as with:

```golang
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /* do things */
}
```

This doesn't satisfy the interface. So we need to create a type that matches the function signature, and provides the interface methods. That's what `http.HandlerFunc` does:

```golang
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

---

If the question is: Why did the authors of the standard library decide to make `ServerHTTP` an interface, rather than a function type, without searching old mailing list archives for clues, only speculation is possible, which is really off-topic here, but here's a small stab at it:

- Interfaces are easier to work with, because they can be easily expanded/embedded. That is, I could implement a struct that satisfies both the `http.Handler` interface, and some other interface. This would be more cumbersome (though not strictly impossible) if `http.Handler` wasn't an interface.
- It's idiomatic. Using an interface for "duck typing" just fits with the Go way of doing things. Maybe that's a bit of a tautology, since the reason it fits with Go is becuase it's done this way.
- If you ever have a complex handler, which maybe tracks its own state, using a struct is the natural solution, and exposing it as an interface is more natural than a closure (which would be required if this were implemented as a function type).

As a thought experiment, just imagine if the [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) interface where instead a function type:

```golang
type Reader func(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

I think it's pretty easy to see that madness would ensue all over the place.

Comment: Their question was more about: why the Go core team developed a single function interface instead of just a function type. It would work likewise.

Comment: @zerkms: If that interpretation is correct, then the question is off-topic as opinion based.

Comment: Not necessarily: there might be some technical aspects that make one option better than the other which OP don't know. But in this case I agree yes.

Comment: Nevertheless, +1d as this is a good answer given the question is not fully clear :-)